# Can not close root window of the navWindow. Close this window instead when trying to close modal

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I get the following error even after having closed the modal.

> Can not close root window of the navWindow. Close this window instead when trying to close modal

Below is my code

```
var mainWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  title : 'My Title',
    barColor : topBarColor,
    backgroundColor : 'white'
  });

var modalWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  modal : true,
  barColor : topBarColor,
  backgroundColor : 'pink'
});

var navWin = Ti.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
  modal: true,
  window: modalWindow
});

navWin.open();
```

This is how I close the windows

```
mainWindow.close();
modalWindow.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the navigationWindow to the modal:

```
var navWin = Ti.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
        modal: true,
        window: modalWindow
});

modalWindow.navWin = navWin;
navWin.open();
```

And then close it like this:

```
modalWindow.navWin.close();
```